# Audio file not playing through platform channel

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to play an audio file on iOS with custom written platform channel. I have no errors when trying to play it, but I can't hear any sound from the phone/simulator.

When I try just_audio everything works great, so the problem is not about file path. You can test the commented method of playing it with just_audio. But when I try to play it through the platform channel, I can't hear any sound

This is my AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import AVFoundation


@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let playerChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "PlayerChannel",
                                                  binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
      playerChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
        [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in
        // This method is invoked on the UI thread.
        guard call.method == "play" else {
          result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
          return
        }
          guard let args = call.arguments as? [String : Any] else {return}
          let text = args["path"] as! String
          
          
          self?.playAudio(result: result, path: text)
      })
      
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    
    
    
   private func playAudio(result: FlutterResult, path: String) {
                
        do{
            
            let audioData = try Data.init(contentsOf:URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(data: audioData) 

        
            
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
            print(String(describing: error))
            result(FlutterError(code: "UNAVAILABLE",
                                   message: "error.",
                                   details: nil))
        }
       
        
     
    }

}
```

And this is how I call this method from my dart file:

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('PlayerChannel');

  Future<String> getPath() async {
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;
    var filePath = "$tempPath/brown_noise.mp3";
    var file = File(filePath);
    if (file.existsSync()) {
      return file.path;
    } else {
      final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/brown_noise.mp3');
      final buffer = byteData.buffer;
      await file.create(recursive: true);
      file.writeAsBytes(
          buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
      return file.path;
    }
  }
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 800), () async {
        try {
        await platform.invokeMethod('play', {'path': await getPath()});
      } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        log("Failed to play: '${e.message}'.");
      }
   /*    final a = AudioPlayer();
      a.setFilePath(await getPath());
      a.play(); */
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

Comment: Just dropping an mp3 into your folder isn't going to work. You will likely need to make it a flutter asset, load it, store it into a temporary file, pass that URL to the plugin.

Comment: @RichardHeap, ok, I'll try, thank you. The part with adding an mp3 file into a folder was taken from native iOS tutorial, so I thought it would work

Comment: @RichardHeap , I've changed the code and it's still not working. I've tried to play it with just_audio and it works fine, but not with platform channel. I've updated my question, can you check the code please?

Comment: Can't see anything obvious with the new code - run the swift in the debugger and see how far it gets.

Comment: @RichardHeap, it goes to the end without exceptions, but doesn't play it

Comment: You may need to go back to the "native iOS tutorial" and see if that works